# child process exit issue (For Excel files the process exiting on closing the opened file but for other files it is exiting after opening the file only

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

```
if (process.platform == 'win32') {
  try {
    let bat = spawn("cmd.exe", [ "/c", path_local, "argument1", "argumentN" ]);

    bat.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    bat.stderr.on("data", (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    bat.on("exit", (code) => {
      console.log(code);
    });

    return;

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
} else {
  shell.openPath(path_local);
}
```

when i open the excel file using child process in node. the exit is hitting fine after i manually closing the associated file , but for other files it is not working. the process is exiting after opening the file.

**Expected**:
The Process should be exited after closing the associated application which is responsible for opening the file